# Problem with understanding a sentence according to the context in a NHK article

Tags: reading-comprehension

[link to the article](https://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/html/20180424/k10011415381000.html?utm_int=netnewsup_contents_list-items_005)

The sentence where I have a problem(at the end of the article):

"このままでは東京オリンピックを境に、数年以内に繁殖農家の“大廃業時代”が訪れる懸念があるのです。"

I don't understand because it doesn't fit the context.廃業 of 繁殖農家 won't be aggraved by the Olympics because the problem isn't about the demand but rather about  a lack of japanese people to continue this activity, even if the demand grows bigger because of the Olympics, it won't make 繁殖農家 disappear further if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this statement is a reference to so-called **2020年問題**, the post-Olympic economic depression that is predicted by many Japanese economists. (It [happened](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%AA%E3%83%AA%E3%83%B3%E3%83%94%E3%83%83%E3%82%AF%E6%99%AF%E6%B0%97) in reality after the first Tokyo Olympics in 1964). Recent Japanese economy has been basically stable thanks to the Olympics, but many people worry about the second "collapse of the Olympic bubble" that may come after 2020. The Olympics is not the only contributing factor; 少子高齢化 is regarded as one of the important aspects of this problem.